# additional information : Could not find a part of the path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, filestream

I am using Asp .net MVC, And I have A log method that's Write on a text file,
the first time it works very well, and the  second time gives me this EXception

> An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'E:\Esam\e-Bank\NewBank\eBank\E-Bank\Admin\Account\Areas\Admin\LogFiles\ScreensLog.txt'.

This is My Code

```
public static void ScreensLog(BaseLog Log)
    {
        FileStream logFileStream = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"Areas/Admin/LogFiles/ScreensLog.txt"),FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter logStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(logFileStream);
        logStreamWriter.WriteLine("["+DateTime.Now+"] "+"\t [User :"+(Log.user.IsEmpty()?"Anonimous":Log.user)+"] \t[Screen :"+Log.screen+"]");
        logStreamWriter.Close();
        logFileStream.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Well obviously the problem is exactly what the exception message says. The directory is not found. So you should check why.

Comment: when I call this function for the first time it writes on the FILE

Comment: Obviously there are differences between the 2 calls. Is the resulting file path the same in both calls? Is the directory deleted between the calls maybe? We cannot help you with that. The method itself looks perfectly fine.

Comment: You should definitely make use of the `using` directive though.

Comment: it does not work